# About to leave academia?

Tags: phd, masters, university, degree

I am about to leave my university in the UK, however I still have access to services for the next few months.

For some background, I initially did my BSc(Hons) at another institution, worked in industry, and then returned to this university to do a master's degree and then the first year of a PhD programme with a full scholarship which I decided not to finish.

Is there a good place to get a list of things that I should do before I leave? I have already spoken to the careers department so I get a list of current jobs in my field, and they have also helped me with both a CV and a Cover Letter for when I apply to new jobs.

Answer (score 4):

Check what's available to you as an alumnus of the university. Things available could include:

- Alumni newsletters. This could include invitations to events in your local town.
- An alumnus email address.
- Subscriptions to certain software programs.

You will need to check to know what's available.